# testbed.createComponents ngsyntax error

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

Hello I am trying to set up karma testing in an angular 2 project however I can't get rid of an error. It was almost always the same, and after using the .catch after createComponents I got the following.

```
   LOG: Error{ngSyntaxError: true, line: 38169, sourceURL:'http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?62c9c9f2f8eb0595c7519c8d7dc8192bb118a027', stack: 'parse@http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?62c9c9f2f8eb0595c7519c8d7dc8192bb118a027:38169:72
_compileTemplate@http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?62c9c9f2f8eb0595c7519c8d7dc8192bb118a027:51920:44
http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?62c9c9f2f8eb0595c7519c8d7dc8192bb118a027:51844:78
forEach@http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?0c8ebfd4331d2badb8d2ce96ff9ff990e8c26a03:1522:12
_compileComponents@http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?62c9c9f2f8eb0595c7519c8d7dc8192bb118a027:51844:26
createResult@http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?62c9c9f2f8eb0595c7519c8d7dc8192bb118a027:51750:37
invoke@http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?0c8ebfd4331d2badb8d2ce96ff9ff990e8c26a03:3039:31
onInvoke@http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?62c9c9f2f8eb0595c7519c8d7dc8192bb118a027:53668:45
onInvoke@http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?62c9c9f2f8eb0595c7519c8d7dc8192bb118a027:54427:47
invoke@http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?0c8ebfd4331d2badb8d2ce96ff9ff990e8c26a03:3038:40
run@http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?0c8ebfd4331d2badb8d2ce96ff9ff990e8c26a03:2789:49
http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?0c8ebfd4331d2badb8d2ce96ff9ff990e8c26a03:3465:60
invokeTask@http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?0c8ebfd4331d2badb8d2ce96ff9ff990e8c26a03:3072:36
onInvokeTask@http://localhost:9876/base/src/test.ts?62c9c9f2f8eb0595c7519c8d7dc8192bb118a027:54454:49
invokeTask@http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?0c8ebfd4331d2badb8d2ce96ff9ff990e8c26a03:3071:48
runTask@http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?0c8ebfd4331d2badb8d2ce96ff9ff990e8c26a03:2839:57
drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?0c8ebfd4331d2badb8d2ce96ff9ff990e8c26a03:3232:42
invoke@http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?0c8ebfd4331d2badb8d2ce96ff9ff990e8c26a03:3138:44
timer@http://localhost:9876/base/src/polyfills.ts?0c8ebfd4331d2badb8d2ce96ff9ff990e8c26a03:4160:34',      __zone_symbol__currentTask: ZoneTask{_zone: Zone{_properties: ..., _parent: ..., _name: ..., _zoneDelegate: ...}, runCount: 0, _zoneDelegates: null, _state: 'notScheduled', type: 'microTask', source: 'Promise.then', data: undefined, scheduleFn: undefined, cancelFn: null, callback: function () { ... }, invoke: function () { ... }}}
```

I am not sure whether someone is capable of making something of this. My source code is below.

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { PlumberAcceptedComponent } from './plumber-accepted.component';


import { DataProvider } from "../../../providers/data.provider";

import { OrderService } from "../order.service";

import { Router } from "@angular/router";

import { AccountProvider } from "../../../providers/account.provider";

import {MockRouter} from '../../../mock';

import * as firebase from 'firebase';




describe('PlumberAcceptedComponent', () => {

  let component: PlumberAcceptedComponent;

  let fixture: ComponentFixture<PlumberAcceptedComponent>;




  beforeEach(async(() => {


    TestBed.configureTestingModule({

  declarations: [PlumberAcceptedComponent],

  imports: [ ],

  providers: [{provide: Router, useClass:MockRouter},

    DataProvider,

    OrderService,

    AccountProvider
  ]
})
  .compileComponents().catch((err)=>{console.log(err);});

 }));


it('should be created', async(() => {
console.log("fdasjklfdjaklfdajfklasdjfklasdjfklasdjklfsdjklfdsjafkldsfasd");
TestBed.compileComponents().then(() => {
  console.log(" fjasdklfjasdklfjdasklfjasd");
const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PlumberAcceptedComponent);

// Access the dependency injected component instance
const app = fixture.componentInstance;


// Access the element
const element = fixture.nativeElement;

// Detect changes as necessary
fixture.detectChanges();

 expect(app).toBeTruthy();  


 }).catch((err)=>{console.log(err);});



 }));

});
```

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Sadly I did not figure it out. Plus this project is finished right now.